# Mosquitto "SSL is disabled"

Tags: mosquitto

I have setup Mosquitto MQTT with SSL on port 8883. However when I try and connect I get an error "Error: A TLS error occurred"

I looked up the mosquitto logs and I see "SSL is disabled" in the logs. 
I don't think that's expected. 
All the certificates are valid.

My config File (Note: mqtt.test.com is not the actual host):

```
autosave_interval 1800
# Persistence Settings
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /tmp/
connection_messages true

# Logging Settings
log_timestamp true
log_dest file /home/ubuntu/mqtt/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

log_type debug

# Port Settings
listener 1883

# Only needed if Websockets
listener 8033
protocol websockets
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.test.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.taggle.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.test.com/privkey.pem

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.test.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.test.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.test.com/privkey.pem
```

Comment: Did you build mosquitto from source?

Comment: Ya. I did. I wanted to use Auth Plugin

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to build mosquitto from source to user the auth_plugin, you need access to the matching src bundle for the version of the broker you have installed.

When you built mosquitto you most likely didn't have the openssl dev packages installed to allow the build to link against openssl.

That or you built mosquitto with `make WITH_TLS=no`

Double check you followed all the instructions in the readme.md that comes with the src and that installed all the prerequisite packages